# Is it possible to print a constantly updating variable on one line?

Tags: python, loops, printing, line

This is just a simple example,

```
import time
for i in range (1,11):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This code counts to 10, but each printed `i` value is on a new line. Is it possible to print them all on the first line, and with each new print, delete that current number, so it counts to 10 in one place?

Comment: See the `end=` keyword argument in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) of the the `print()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use sys.stdout.write.

```
import sys
import time
for i in range (1,11):
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add '\r' before the number to be printed, this would return the carriage and overwrite last line:

```
import time
for i in range (1,11):
    print(f'\r{i}', end='')
    time.sleep(1)
# Add print after loop for a new line, when finishing
print()
```